# How I can make a gradient with three opposite points?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a color picker just like in the picture, but I could not do the triangle, which has three points to show the gradient, White, Black and the selected color.

The black and white are always the same, but the color selected should vary according to the user selects in the circle, but do not know how to make a gradient opposite to those three points, and displays the image.

(Only objective c, please)

Hope, someone could help me. Thanks.

[HSL Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZCD7.jpg)

Comment: so when you rotate the triangle , you want to show the gradient (of the three edges) inside the traingle   ?

Comment: No @Mr.t, the triangle is static, as the wheel, the user will point any color of the circle with the finger, and the selected color will change in the triangle, showing the white, the black, and the selected color. And, inside the triangle, if the user wants a brighter color, or darker, just move the finger inside the triangle, to adjust the color.

Comment: I think you have to overlay 3 layers: 1) solid picked color 2) full white to clear 3) black to clear. I'm not sure if that will be exact match thou but I think this is a start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can try to create gradient with three colors:

Get the reference from your triangle edges that have the reference to the color they point to.

```
BOOL isHorizontal=YES;
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.bounds;

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[self.startColor CGColor],(id)[self.midColor CGColor], (id)[self.endColor CGColor], nil];
gradient.endPoint = (self.isHorizontal) ? CGPointMake(1, 0) : CGPointMake(0, 1);
[self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

If you want to change the gradient direction, play around with:

```
    [gradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [gradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];
```

Comment: While good information, this will only create a linear gradient, and not a gradient between 3 points(with x,y coordinates and distinct colors) like the triangle image shows.

Comment: I agree ,but I didnt find any resource that creates a unique gradient for 3 colors. What i find is a liner gradient. Please provide any additional info if you have.

Comment: @Mr.T Please see my comment above.

Comment: Yes @Kekoa if you have any idea, it would be great if you share with us.

Comment: @Mr.T I can't think of a simple solution off the top of my head. One possibility involves drawing with OpenGL, as shaders will naturally interpolate the colors of vertices for you, and the other would involve lots of processing to manually generate a UIImage programmatically, by setting each pixel's color manuall(this would be slow). At the moment, that's all I have, but I'll keep thinking.